# How can I perform a regex/text search on a SUPER type?

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

### What I'm doing now:

- I have a table with one field that is a json value that is stored as a super type in my staging schema.
- the field containing the json is called `elements`
- In my clean table, I typecast this field to `VARCHAR` in order to search it and use string functions
- I want to search for the string `net` within that json in order to determine the key/value that I want to use for my filter
- I tried the following:

```sql
select 
    elements
    , elements_raw
from clean.events
where 1=1
  and lower(elements) like '%net%'
  or strpos(elements,'net')
```

### My output

- When running the above query, I keep getting an empty set returned.

### My issue

- I tried running the above code and using the `elements_raw` value instead but I got an issue :`ERROR: function strpos(super, "unknown") does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.`
- I checked the [redshift super page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SUPER_type.html) and it doesn't list any specifics on searching strings within super types

#### Desired result:

- Perform string operations on super field
- Cast super field to a string type

Answer (score 1):

There are some `super` related idiosyncrasies that are being run into here:

1. You cannot change the type of a `super` field via `::` or `cast()`
2. String functions `like` and `strpos` do not work on `super` types

To address both of these issues, you can use the function `json_serialize` to return your super as a string.